# Adding newline to byte sequence when writing to filestream

Tags: c#, encoding, filestream

I am trying to add `Newline` when writing to a `FileStream` and it seems that even if i try :
`\r\n` or
`\\r\\n` or
`System.Environment.Newline` 
the result file will not add the newlines.It will just add the characters as they are:

`public static NewLine=>System.Environment.Newline;`

```
 string header = $"Client:{index}{Newline}Date:{DateTime.Now.ToString()}{Newline}\r\nData:{Newline}";
 using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate,FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))   
 {
    await stream.WriteAsync(header.ToMemory());

    ReadOnlyMemory<byte> memory = Enumerable.Aggregate(
                                    responses,
                                    string.Empty,
                                    (acc, src) => acc + Newline + src.ToString()).ToMemory();
    await stream.WriteAsync(memory);
 }
```

In our case `NewLine` is `System.Environment.Newline`, but i have tried all of the above combinations and the output of the file is:

```
"Client:0\r\nDate:23.08.2018 21:56:04\r\n\r\nData:\r\n""\r\n00:00:00.3222976"510"
```

And i wanted

```
 Client:0
 Date:23.08.2018 
 Data:  --data should start from below
 00:00:00.3222976 510
 .........
```

**ToMemory**

```
 public static ReadOnlyMemory<byte> ToMemory(this object obj)
        {
            string dataString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
            ReadOnlyMemory<byte> dataBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataString);
            return dataBytes;
        }
```

Comment: Then maybe `Newline == "\\r\\n"`? Your Newline constant is not correct.

Comment: Have you tried the hex values  0x0A  and 0x0D?

Comment: In the current form its `public static Newline=>System.Environment.Newline`

Comment: You need to use a System.IO.StreamWriter or System.Text.Encoding to transform your String values into bytes.

Comment: @usr is right...the `JsonSerializer` was escaping my characters and yes i will use `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a string to `ToMemory` which converts it to JSON. The JSON serializer then, correctly, escapes the newline characters.

The fix seems to be to simply not encode as JSON. Write the string to the stream directly.